# Favorite Question and Answers from Second Quarter 2022

Tags: discussion, blog

### Update

[Blog Post](https://thesffblog.com/2022/07/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-second-quarter-2022/)

### Original

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2022 through June 30th 2022.

> enter the following capatcha to prove you aren't a robot. "I am a robot"

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](https://thesffblog.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/04/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/04/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2022/04/01)

**I will be linking all blog posts that happened within this quarter year. Also the [most controversial question](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/1483709/1819138/most-controversial-posts-on-the-site-by-start-date) of the quarter. Also a sum of all the [bounties](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/1483710/1819137/past-bounties-by-bounty-date) that were awarded.**

Additionally if there was a meta post you feel should be spotlighted those are also acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed answering this one:

[What changes were made for the second edition of 'The Martian'?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263050/what-changes-were-made-for-the-second-edition-of-the-martian)

It's the sort of question I like, where deep research will produce something comprehensive.